# Don't understand cause of this json JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json

Can anyone give me a newb tip on loading a json file into Python?

If I use:

```
import json

config_file = "./setpoints.json"
hvac_setpoints = json.loads(config_file)

print(hvac_setpoints)
```

On this `setpoints.json` file:

```
{ "setpoint": {
"ahu_static_sp_start": 0.75,
"ahu_static_sp_min": 0.15,
"ahu_static_sp_max": 1.5,
"static_sp_trim": -0.04,
"static_sp_increase": 0.06,
"time_delay_startup": 300,
"time_delay_normal": 120,
"vav_ignore_requests": 1,
"num_of_vav_above_hi_dpr_stp": 2,
"high_vav_dpr_stp": 90}
}
```

I'll get an `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` in Python:

```
~\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Did you mean: `hvac_setpoints = json.load(open(config_file))`? At the moment you are parsing the filename, not the contents of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use a structure as follows

```
with open("setpoints.json", 'r') as file:
    hvac_setpoints = json.load(file)
```

Comment: You don't need the `'r'` as this is the default mode.

Comment: @baduker: Hardly matters (and besides, see second line of [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).